timestamps written by java.sql.SQLData are shifted by timezone specific number of hours
Can someone advice, why writing data using java.sql.SQLData shifts timestamps by N hours, where N is timezone offset?
Background: I have app using hibernate 6 and springboot 3, I need to call stored procedure, which accepts list of custom type. Very specific task, nothing too trivial. I spent 1-2 weeks elaborating how to do it in hibernate 6 and 5 and few days on hibernate fora talking to the best. This sadly didn't yield any MWE, it should be possible somehow, no one was able to show any working sample. I don't want to proceed in this direction. So I implemented it using JdbcTemplate spring util.
State: Implementation 'works', data are persisted. But java.sql.Timestamp instances are persisted time 'shifted'. In implementation below, instance of Instant from field someEntity.getCalculatedTimestamp() is say 10:00:00Z. Correct. After conversion Timestamp.from(someEntity.getCalculatedTimestamp()); the to toString reports 'shifted'(12:00:00, my TZ is +2), but that's normal(tostring reports it in local timezone), the deprecated toGMTString reports correct data(10:00:00 GMT). The only available method to write this into SQLOutput is method stream.writeTimestamp. But when I check datasource proxy logs, 'shifted' timestamp goes to db. SO, I guess the oracle driver must have shifted it somehow.
nasty workaround: I guess I can count on this being stable unwanted behavior, and just move timestamp by known amount to opposite direction to cancel out oracle driver unwanted 'fix', but I really don't like it. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to prevent it?
implementation:
jdbcTemplate.call(con -> {
        CallableStatement callableStatement = con.prepareCall(PROCEDURE_NAME);
        OracleConnection oracleConnection = con.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);

        Array oracleArray = oracleConnection.createOracleArray(PROCEDURE_ARRAY_TYPE_NAME,
                inputArray);

        callableStatement.setArray(1, oracleArray);
        return callableStatement;

    }, Collections.singletonList(new SqlParameter(Types.STRUCT)));

and type of each item in array is:
public class TTT implements SQLData {
        private static final String SQL_TYPE = "%s.%s".formatted("someSchema", "someType");

        private UUID id;
        private Timestamp calculatedTimestamp;

        public TTT() {
        }

        public TTT(SomeEntity someEntity) {
            this.id = someEntity.getId();
            this.calculatedTimestamp = Timestamp.from(someEntity.getCalculatedTimestamp());
            
        }

        @Override
        public String getSQLTypeName() {
            return SQL_TYPE;
        }

        @Override
        public void readSQL(SQLInput stream,
                            String typeName) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented yet");
        }

        @Override
        public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException {
            stream.writeBytes(UuidUtil.uuidToByteArray(id));
            stream.writeTimestamp(calculatedTimestamp);
            
            //unsupported, fails.
//            stream.writeObject(calculatedTimestamp, OracleType.TIMESTAMP_WITH_LOCAL_TIME_ZONE);
//            stream.writeObject(calculatedTimestamp, OracleType.TIMESTAMP);
        }
    }

EDIT, workaround code:
private Timestamp nastyTimestampHackConversion(Instant instant) {
        if (instant == null) {
            return null;
        }

        long offsetSecondsDiff = ZoneId.systemDefault().getRules().getOffset(instant).getTotalSeconds();
        Instant fixedInstant = instant.plus(-1*offsetSecondsDiff, ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
        return Timestamp.from(fixedInstant);
    }


Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE statement for your table so we know whether the column is DATE, TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE or TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE  in Oracle.

" The only available method to write this into SQLOutput is method stream.writeTimestamp" You also have writeObject(Object x, SQLType targetSqlType)

My guess is that you are using a java.sql.Timestamp which is not time-zone aware and either when you store it in the database or when you retrieve it then the non-time-zone aware data is retrieved and converted to the local time zone. To solve it, use time-zone aware data-types throughout the process.

@MTO I didn't mentioned it explicitly enough, only in comment. Oracle driver does not implement writeObject method. This cannot be used. ~ Sorry about not being specific enough again, the data type is TIMESTAMP(6). I can create MWE eventually, but I had to fix it asap (nasty workaround) as I detected this issue only too late and my time is running out.

@MTO regarding your guess. Yes, I'm using java.sql.Timestamp which is not zone-aware (except tostring method), storing it into TIMESTAMP(6). Reading is done via hibernate Instant field in entity (also not timezone aware).,Retrieval part wasn't updated. Before I insert/read the data using this entity. It was correct. Now I write them using this procedure, mismatch. So reading part ins't the one to blame. Also data proxy shows, that writer is the one to blame, wrong data are passed to db. ~ I cannot use timezone aware data type (now) ~ I used nasty workaround and 'it saves the day'.

Assuming someEntity.getCalculatedTimestamp() returns a time-zone aware data-type then convert it to the UTC time zone and then store it in the database as UTC then when you want to read it as UTC, convert it back to a time-zone aware data-type in your local time zone.

@MT0 no, someEntity.getCalculatedTimestamp() is Instant.
